# Drawing edges between nodes in Tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have a tikz image:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, draw=green!60, fill=green!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm}, squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=5mm},>=stealth]
\node[squarednode, rounded corners] (1) {Some Text};
\node[squarednode, rounded corners, right=of 1] (2) {Some Text};
\node[squarednode, rounded corners, right=of 2] (3) {Some Text};
\draw[->] (1) edge node {} (2);
\draw[->] (2) edge node {} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to create a connection between the 3rd block and the 1st block as depicted below.

[image]

I don't know how to let the edge start on the right side of the 3rd block and end at the left side of the 1st block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, all of which are variations of what you already did. You can use lines with corners like so:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=5mm,rounded corners},>=stealth]
        \node[squarednode] (1) {Some Text};
        \node[squarednode, right=of 1] (2) {Some Text};
        \node[squarednode, right=of 2] (3) {Some Text};
        \draw[->] (1) -- (2);
        \draw[->] (2) -- (3);
        \draw[->] (3.east) -| ++(.5,-1) -- ($(1.west)+(-.5,-1)$) |- (1.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like so:

[image]

OR: You can use a line with specified exit and entrance angles, like so:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=5mm,rounded corners},>=stealth]
        \node[squarednode] (1) {Some Text};
        \node[squarednode, right=of 1] (2) {Some Text};
        \node[squarednode, right=of 2] (3) {Some Text};
        \draw[->] (1) -- (2);
        \draw[->] (2) -- (3);
        \draw[->] (3.east) to[out=-20,in=200] (1.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like so:

[image]

Note of caution: Using the exit-entrance angles, you will end up with extra white space to the sides of the image, so you may want to `clip` the image to the desired size manually.

**EDIT:** To clip the image to the desired size, again there are many ways to this, but for me the easiest way is to first `draw` a rectangle around the image to make sure everything is on the inside and then replace `draw` by `clip`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=5mm,rounded corners},>=stealth]
        \draw (-1.5,-1) rectangle (7.3,1); % replace \draw with \clip
        \node[squarednode] (1) {Some Text};
        \node[squarednode, right=of 1] (2) {Some Text};
        \node[squarednode, right=of 2] (3) {Some Text};
        \draw[->] (1) -- (2);
        \draw[->] (2) -- (3);
        \draw[->] (3.east) to[out=-20,in=200] (1.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! How does the clipping work? I exactly have the issue that there is a lot of white space.

Comment: I added some instructions to get you started. Note: This is certainly not the most sophisticated approach, but it gets the job done.